# Inserting Multiple Rows from a dataGridview into a single row in Microsoft Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to insert multiple rows from a datagridView to a single row in the Microsoft Access table. The application is a Point of Sale system.

I have been able to add the multiple rows from the datagrid to the database table but it saves them separately in the table. I want it saved in the single row of the database table.

```
Private Sub btn_Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click
    Try
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\inventory1.accdb")
            cn.Open()
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_order_cart.Rows
                Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblTransaction (Product_Name,Price,Qty,Amount) VALUES (@Product_Name,@Price,@Qty,@Amount)", cn)
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", OleDbType.VarChar)
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", OleDbType.Currency)
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", OleDbType.Decimal)
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", OleDbType.Currency)

                    With cmd2
                        .Parameters("@Product_Name").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
                        .Parameters("@Price").Value = row.Cells(1).Value
                        .Parameters("@Qty").Value = row.Cells(2).Value
                        .Parameters("@Amount").Value = row.Cells(3).Value
                    End With

                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            'End Using 'You probably want to catch more specific exceptions
            'and handle them separately
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception 'You probably want to catch more specific exceptions
        'and handle them separately
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show("TRANSACTION INSERTED SUCCESFULLY")
End Sub
```

I want the Multiple records from the datagridview to be saved in a single row in the database table.

Comment: Why would you want to save multiple values into a single record? This is not normalized structure. Exactly which data do you want to combine into single field? In loop, concatenate values into CSV string variable. Then outside the loop, run an INSERT action with that variable.

Comment: Why would each row of DataGridVIew NOT be a separate record? Seems like the records are missing an ID that would associate the items with the same transaction. Should there also be a transaction date?

Comment: This looks like an Order Details table. Do not combine the rows in the grid into a single record. What you need is an Order Id field to use for each record in the order details. This would come from the primary key of an Orders table which would contain Order Date, Customer, etc.

Comment: @June7,  thank you for the insight.  The program is a Point of Sale software.  You know a customer might buy more than one item in the store,  I want all the items purchased to be in one single row in the database.  I will still generate an auto ID for each transaction but I want all items purchased by a customer to have a single Transaction ID.  And also,  when I call the transaction ID in a report,  it should bring all the items purchased by the specific customer

Comment: Still, as @Mary also said, each item should be its own record with a foreign key relating to parent Order record. The Order record would have OrderID, customer name, date. OrderID would also be saved as foreign key for each product record in OrderDetails. Combining into a single record really makes no sense. Would have to concatenate to a single long string. Or drop those details and save only total sale amount into Order record.

Comment: @June7,  I will try it out.  Thanks for the response